# Rails: Structuring rental orders & order form in ecommerce-like setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, e-commerce

I was wondering if someone could help me out with an application that has some ecommerce characteristics.

**Context:** Via the application a bike shop chain ('chains') can rent out

- bikes ('*bikes*'),
- by picking out a bike type such as mountainbike, city bike etc. ('*bike_types*) and
- bike options, such as helmets etc. ('*bike_options*')
- which are dependent on the individual bike store ('*bike_stores*')
- this rental of the bikes & options will all be captured in an order ('*orders*')
- the relationship between orders and bikes is many-to-many, therefore I created a  table to bridge this ('*order_bikes*')

**Final notes:**

- Before the rental process, the chain owner first created his/her *(i) bike_stores, (ii) bike_types, (iii) bikes and (iv) bike_options*, this part of the application is working. Therefore, he/she only needs to select bike_types/bikes/options out of the existing inventory previously created.
- I limit the scope of the question by leaving out the bike_options, this was mainly to provide some context in order to understand the db schema build up.

**Error message:** Unpermitted parameter: :bike_id

**Code:**

*models*

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike_store
  has_many :bike_types, through: :bike_store
  has_many :order_bikes, inverse_of: :order, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_bikes, allow_destroy: true
end


class OrderBike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike
  belongs_to :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bike
end


class Bike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike_type
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :order_bikes
  has_many :orders, through: :order_bikes
end


class BikeType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike_store
  has_many :bikes, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bikes, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :bike_options, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bike_options, allow_destroy: true
  validates :name, :bike_count, presence: true
end

class BikeStore < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bike_types, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Order controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_bikes.build
    @bike_type_list = @bike_store.bike_types
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order.bike_store = @bike_store
    @order.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:arrival, :departure,
      order_bikes_attributes: [:id, :bike_quantity, :_destroy,
        bikes_attributes: [:id, :name,
          bike_types_attributes: [:id, :name]]])
  end
end
```

view

```
<%= simple_form_for [@bike_store, @order] do |f|%>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :order_bikes do |order_bike| %>
  <%= order_bike.input :bike_quantity %>
  <%= order_bike.association :bike %>
<% end %>

 <%= f.input :arrival %>
 <%= f.input :departure %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check coed from simple form [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L206), you will see what actually method association does.

```
def association(association, options = {}, &block)
  # ... simple form code here ...
  attribute = build_association_attribute(reflection, association, options)

  input(attribute, options.merge(reflection: reflection))
end
```

We are interested in `build_association_attribute` method call. [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L510)

```
def build_association_attribute(reflection, association, options)
  case reflection.macro
  when :belongs_to
    (reflection.respond_to?(:options) && reflection.options[:foreign_key]) || :"#{reflection.name}_id"
    # ... the rest of code ...
  end
end
```

Your order bike model has `belongs_to :bike` association. So when you call `order_bike.association :bike` it builds `:bike_id` attribute in your form. If you check `params` hash that comes to your controller, I believe you'll see that attribute coming from your view.

I added `bike_id` to permitted parameters. I hope it will fix your problem..

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:arrival, :departure,
    order_bikes_attributes: [:id, :bike_id, :bike_quantity, :_destroy,
      bikes_attributes: [:id, :name,
        bike_types_attributes: [:id, :name]]])
end
```

Comment: Wow, that indeed did the trick. Thank you as well for the elaboration, that was really insightful!